# WPF and Creating Objects and why aren't certain properties being set? (MVVM, EF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am not sure why my properties defined in the XAML are not being exposed in the ViewModel? Here is my current application: have a WPF 4.5 project using the MVVM pattern with Entity Framework 6.0.

When I am attempting to CREATE a new object upon Save(), say Employee, I instantiate an Employee object within the EmployeeViewModel with some default values, i.e. like so:

C#

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{

    private Employee _employee;
    public Employee Employee
    {
        get
        {
            return _employee;
        }
        set
        {
            _employee = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Employee");
        }
    }

    public EmployeeViewModel()
    {
        Employee = new Employee();
        Employee.HireDate = DateTime.Now;
            ...
    }



}
```

XAML:

```
...
<TextBox Text="{Binding Employee.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Employee.LastName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Employee.Salary, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
...
```

I know from the above XAML that the Path, e.g. "Employee.FirstName" is being found for those properties because I do not get a warning noting that it cannot figure out what Employee is. FYI, I set the DataContext for this XAML like so:

```
DataContext="{Binding Path=EmployeeViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
```

Though I am not explicitly setting the FirstName, LastName, etc. Employee properties in the ViewModel, shouldn't they still be set through the public property of Employee in the ViewModel?

I also set some breakpoints on the properties defined within the Employee class located where my Entity Framework Code First is defined and those are not hit.

So, via the form when I enter data and then click on a Save button which calls a Save method in the EmployeeViewModel that takes an Employee object as a parameter, I can see that the Employee object does not have any of the properties set that are suppose to be coming from the XAML and the only properties I see populated are the ones I initially set via the ViewModel's constructor.

What am I missing?

---

EDIT 1:

Here is my Save method and this is where I investigate the Employee object and it has the same properties as when it was instantiated via the EmployeeViewModel's constructor:

```
public void Save()
{
    AddEmployee(Employee);
}
```

I am pretty sure it is the same Employee object from the constructor because of the TimeStamps on it.

---

EDIT 2:

My Employee class is defined within a project that is basically an EF Code First project. Here is a part of my class:

```
 [Table("Employee")]
 public partial class Employee
 {
     public Employee()
     {
         Projects = new ICollection<Project>();
     }

     public int EmpId{ get; set; }

     [StringLength(50)]
     public string FirstName { get; set; }

     ...
```

Comment: Where is the `Employee` object coming from that is the parameter to the command? Are you sure it is the same instance as the one that is a member of `EmployeeViewModel`?

Comment: @Andy: I have added a section, Edit 1, thanks.

Comment: Have you implmented INotifyPropertyChanged in your Employee class? How does AddEmployee function look like?

Comment: @Matan: I have added a section, Edit 2, hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your Employee Class: (The binding is on the properties of your Employee, it won't get notify when the properties are being updated)

```
    [Table("Employee")]
    public partial class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Employee()
        {
            Projects = new ICollection<Project>();
        }

        private int _empId;
        public int EmpId 
        {
            get
            {
                return _empId;
            }
            set
            {
                _empId = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("EmpId");
            }
        }

        private string _firstName;
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string FirstName
        {
            get
            {
                return _firstName;
            }
            set
            {
                _firstName = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

Try reading this article it may have a native way for binding a database object in WPF. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547149.aspx)

Comment: I was under the assumption that these EF classes should be as much as POCOs as possible, i.e. without INotifyPropertyChanged for example? Nonetheless, I will go ahead and implement your suggestion and report back, thanks!

Comment: If you want to keep Employee class as POCO you can use another layer which is to create another class that will be called "EmployeeView" or something which it's purpose is to present an Employee object, it will observe an Employee instance and the binding will be applied on him. But it's a lot more work.

Comment: Also if you don't want to do all the work of duplicating every field in your view model then it's possible to add change notification to all the members automatically. The basic idea is you mark your members virtual and then use something like Castle Dynamic Proxy to inject change notification for you. I haven't used this with EF yet but I did use it for NHibernate and it worked quite well.

Comment: @MarkFeldman, a very good idea re: Castle Dynamic Proxy, thanks!